# Strange behavior of shared memory in php

Tags: php, multithreading, shared-memory

I'm using shmop and pcntl exts in this way:
1. Fork few threads
2. Open shared memory segment with the same key in all forked threads and in the main thread.
3. Write/Read to/from segment.
4. Delete and create segment with it's original name with bigger size.

Sometimes my code works properly and all threads change values so other threads can use these values. But in most cases threads work like "there's not a segment with provided id." Although above this complaints clearly shows that one of threads already created a segment with the same id.

To discover that segment is not yet created, I try to open it with 'w' flag, and if it complains about non-existent segment, I create it with 'c' flag.

Method that does this work:

```
protected function open() {
    // probe
    echo '=== KEY IS: '.$this->key.PHP_EOL;
    $this->memory = shmop_open($this->key, 'w', 0, 0);
    if ($this->memory === false) {
        echo getmypid().'Create segment'.PHP_EOL;
        $this->memory = shmop_open($this->key, 'c', 0666, strlen(serialize($this->initialValue)));
    } else {
        echo getmypid().'Open segment'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

My output is here:

```
I am child: 6370
...
=== KEY IS: 1895898008
PHP Warning:  shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment in /home/debian/MiniThreader/src/CommonStorage.php on line 90
...
I am child: 6369
...
I am child: 6368
...
6370Create segment
Expanding size from 6 to 17
New size is 17
...
=== KEY IS: 1895898008
6369Open segment
...
Expanding size from 17 to 28
...
=== KEY IS: 1895898008
6368Open segment
...
Expanding size from 28 to 39
New size is 39
...
I am child: 6367
...
=== KEY IS: 1895898008
PHP Warning:  shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment in /home/debian/MiniThreader/src/CommonStorage.php on line 90
6367Create segment
...
Expanding size from 6 to 17
New size is 17
...
=== KEY IS: 1895898008
PHP Warning:  shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment in /home/debian/MiniThreader/src/CommonStorage.php on line 90
6366Create segment
string(6) ""
```

In this code all threads trying to add their process identificator to an array, and increases it if there's a need.

- First thread (6369) can't find a shared segment, so it creates one = *right*
- After that, second thread (6370) can find previously created segment, so it uses it = *right*
- After that, third thread (6368) does the same = *right*
- But fourth thread (6367) did not find the segment and creates a new one. = *wrong*
- And after all that the main thread also did not find the segment and creates it again = *wrong*.

So, my question is: Why sometimes threads can't work properly with shared segments, and what a nature of this behavior on lower level?

And yes, I'm using a semaphore to prevent simultaneosly expanding:

```
protected function expand($newsize) {
    sem_acquire($this->sizeSemaphore);

    shmop_delete($this->memory);
    $this->memory = shmop_open($this->key, 'c', 0644, $newsize);

    sem_release($this->sizeSemaphore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### It is about destructors

This question is not about memory. Destructors (__destruct) is the answer.

For those, who faced the same problems with shared memory or anything else, consider rewrite your destructors that can delete data before you actually wanted to do.

In my case class that works with memory segment had code in destructor that deletes memory segment. But this action is intended to be in main thread only.